# Using Matlab GA for optimization of expensive fitness function with Constraints

Tags: matlab, optimization, constraints, genetic-algorithm

I am using *Genetic Algorithm in Matlab* for optimization of a **computationally expensive fitness function which also has constraints** . I am right now imposing constraints in the form of **penalty** in to the objective function since *constraint violation can only be calculated at the end of the function evaluation*. I wanted to use nonlcon rather to satisfy the constraints.

But my problem is that the fitness function evaluation is **expensive** and I can't afford to do it again for checking of constraint violation. I have seen some nested function formulations where using output function I can accumulate all the individual variable values for every generation.

As per what I was thinking, Would it be possible to have sort of a matrix in which I can store all the individual values at the beginning of a generation update that matrix while my fitness evaluations and when I call nonlcon for constraint evaluation, then to look up that updated matrix for constraint violation. While I am trying to implement this, I have some doubts.

1) I remember reading in some forum that outputfcn for Genetic algo can be called either at the *beginning* of a generation or at *the end*. By default, it is at the end. I wont be able to execute my method if it calls at the end. Sadly I am not able to find how to call the outputfcn at the beginning rather than the end of a generation.

2) Since my fitness function is computationally expensive, I am using Parallel evaluations. So Would it be possible to implement the above mentioned idea while using parallel option in Matlab or it would create some difficulties?

Answer (score 0):

Are you still looking for an answer? I had a similar problem and solved it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22558894/can-the-genetic-algorithm-in-matlab-pass-a-second-return-value-from-the-fitness). I use two anonymous functions `fitnessFunction` and `nonlconFunction` in the ga which both point to my `switchOutput` function. They just pass an additional flag which output is requested. In the `switchOutput`, the expensive calculation is done for the first call with a specific input set and the results are stored. If there is another call with the same input set, the stored results are returned.

With this setup it doesn't matter it which order you call your fitness function and your constraint function. For the first call with a new input set, the results will be calculated and for any subsequent calls with the same inputs the saved results will be returned!